# TPM 1.2 pass through to a Win10 Guest

Tags: 16.04, kvm-virtualization, tpm

I spun up and Win10 image I need for my work on my 16.04 LTS Desktop and this image requires access to a TPM device.  Now, I've added a TPM pass through to the Guest via VM but the VM won't spin up.  I am getting the following error:

```
 Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-04-24T19:22:43.438325Z qemu-system-x86_64: -tpmdev passthrough,id=tpm-tpm0,path=/dev/fdset/1,cancel-path=/dev/fdset/2: '/dev/fdset/1' is not a TPM device.**"
```

I've found  the path for the TPM functions is `/sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device`

did anyone encounter this one? can anyone help?

`libvirt` version is 1.3.1 and `QEMU` version is 2.5

Thx in advance!
Gil

Comment: Hi All, another thing i noticed is the following dmesg entry repeating  each time the TPM guest is tring to boot:   [59054.898336] audit: type=1400 audit(1462085915.396:347): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_perm" profile="libvirt-7e2619a1-319d-43b6-95da-1be7af22e936" name="/dev/tpm0" pid=10433 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=122 ouid=122  .. so i've tried to put the libvirtd app and all related profiles in complain mode but to no avail.. can someone please help with this one.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late response, but I edited /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu and added the following:

/dev/tpm0 rw,

above:

/dev/net/tun rw,
/dev/tap* rw,
/dev/kvm rw,
It was at line 23.